# How to extend the rich text input of lwc with custom buttons to add new commands?

Tags: lightning-web-components

[Documentation of the lwc component for rich text input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation) 
(lightning-input-rich-text ...) indicates that you can add custom buttons.

```
<lightning-input-rich-text
    custom-buttons={myCustomButtons}>
</lightning-input-rich-text>
```

the example shows how to pop up an alert when a custom button is pressed which does make limited sense....

```
handler: function () {
         alert('Like Button Clicked');
}
```

I need to add custom buttons to allow for header formatting (which is not included in the standard button list). 
How can I access the underlying editor (quill) functions to make selected text formatted with header tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome debugger of the component indicates, that the handler function has acccess to  "this.quill" which makes available the [quill API](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/). 
Hence to format the current select with a button click as heading 1 with
`this.quill.format('header','h1');`

The full code snipped then is

```
 customButtons = [
    {
        category: "FORMAT_TEXT",
        label: 'Format Text',
        buttons: [
            {
                value: 'like',
                label: 'Like',
                iconName: 'utility:like',
                format: 'like',
                handler: function () {
                    // format selection to be h1...
                    this.quill.format('header', 'h1'); 
                }
            }
        ]
    },

];
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work, can you provide any more input on how to get this working?

Comment: Has anyone succeeded to access the underlying quill api ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work..

```
 customButtons = [
    {
        category: "FORMAT_TEXT",
        label: 'Format Text',
        buttons: [
            {
                value: 'like',
                label: 'Like',
                iconName: 'utility:like',
                format: 'header',
                handler: function () {
                    // format selection to be h1...
                    this.quill.format('header', 'h1');
                }
            }
        ]
    },

];
```

You got to make sure 'format' is set to 'header'.
Also, if you use the formats attribute, make sure 'header' is in there :)